# Split a string but keep the delimiter

Tags: regex, arrays, vb.net, string, split

I have this string:

> S40102S40078S40079S40080S40053S40052S40051S40050

but my code of

```
Dim MyArray() As String = MyString.Split("S")
```

removes the S but i want to keep it, I've tried RegEx but I cant get it to work, any help much appreciated.

thanks

Comment: If you know what you are splitting on, why do you need to keep it? Where do you need to keep it? Start of each "split"? End? Both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use positive lookahead and split on the zero length match before an "S": `(?=S)`

I hope this works in VB.

Thanks @Oded for your comment. To avoid splitting on the first S you can do something like that: `(?=[^\a]S)`

Comment: First result will be empty. All other results will contain the `S` at the start, which may or may not be what the OP is after.

Comment: Oded, your (?=S) did the trick for me and I just removed the first result from my Array before adding it to the ComobBox. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a delimiter between the digit before the `S` then split on that delimiter. Eg

```
Dim MyArray() As String = Regex.Replace(MyString, "(\d)S", "$1-S").Split("-")
```

Note: VB.NET isn't my first language so please check syntax is correct

Answer (score 0):

I think regex will work on this.  Something like this:

```
Dim input As String = "S40102S40078S40079S40080S40053S40052S40051S40050"
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("([^S])*[S]")
Dim ms As MatchCollection = regex.Matches(input)
Dim MyArray() As String
Dim ctr As Integer = 0

'loop through them all
foreach(m As Match In ms)
{
    'assign to array
    MyArray(ctr) = m.Value

    'increase counter
    ctr += 1
}
```

This is untested and is a port from C# so the syntax may be a bit off, but it's very close.